# How to draw rectangle in pdf viewer using pdf.js and fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs, pdf.js

I have used following links and developed the pdf viewer
https://pdfjs.express/blog/how-to-use-pdf-js

Comment: And we have [ask] to explain the minimum requirements for a halfway proper question.